# spring-ws: no endpoint mapping found

Tags: spring, web-services, soapui, spring-ws, endpoint

I made a simple web service but when I'am trying to test it on soapui its giving this error:

```
WARN : [Oct-11 12:56:38,081] ws.server.EndpointNotFound - No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.servesy.com/api/v1/service}signupRequest]
```

I do not have any idea what should I do to make it correct, I saw many questions regarding this problem but did not find any solution.

My spring-ws configuration are follows:
(apart from this configuration I also tried to make simple input output example and that 
also shows same warning)

**web.xml**

```
<web-app 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/config/servesy-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servesyservices</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servesyservices</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.wsdl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servesyservices</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/endpoints/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**servesy-config.xml**

```
<beans 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.servesy.webservices" />
    <sws:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="ServesyService" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="schemaCollection">
            <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
                <property name="inline" value="true" />

                    <property name="xsds">
                        <list>
                            <value>schemas/ServesyServices.xsd</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>

            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="portTypeName" value="ServesyService"/>
        <property name="serviceName" value="ServesyServices" />
        <property name="locationUri" value="/endpoints"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Endpoint**

```
@Endpoint
public class ServesyWebServiceEndpoint {

        private static final String TARGET_NAMESPACE ="http://www.servesy.com/api/v1/service";


        private ServesyWebService servesyservice_i;

        @Autowired
        public void setServesyWebService(ServesyWebService servesyservice_p)
        {
            this.servesyservice_i = servesyservice_p;
        }



        @PayloadRoot(localPart="SignupRequest", namespace=TARGET_NAMESPACE)
        public @ResponsePayload SignupResponse response(SignupRequest signupRequest) {

            SignupResponse signupResponse = new SignupResponse();
            Signup signup = servesyservice_i.signupResponse( signupRequest.getMobileNumber(), signupRequest.getPassword(), signupRequest.getCustomerName(), signupRequest.getEmailId(), signupRequest.getPromoCode(), signupRequest.getDevice());
            signupResponse.setSignup(signup);
            return signupResponse;
        }

        @PayloadRoot(localPart="LoginRequest", namespace=TARGET_NAMESPACE)
        public @ResponsePayload LoginResponse response(LoginRequest loginRequest) {

            LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
            String string = servesyservice_i.signinResponse( loginRequest.getEmailID(), loginRequest.getPassword(), loginRequest.getDevice());
            loginResponse.setSessionId(string);
            return loginResponse;
        }
    }
```

and my soupui gives this type of blank output:
[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `EndpointNotFoundException` occurs when Spring-WS cannot find a suitable `@Endpoint` that can handle the incoming request.

In this case, the incoming message has namespace `http://www.servesy.com/api/v1/service` and local name `signupRequest` (as can be seen in the log). While your `@PayloadRoot` mapping does have the same namespace; it does not have the same local name, as it uses `SignupRequest` with a capital S. Chances are that if you change the uppercase S to a lower case s in the `@PayloadRoot` annotation, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar issue and the root cause was in the application servlet context path.

The best way how to approach this problem is, in my opinion, to set **DEBUG** logging level for **"org.springframework.ws"** and carefully watch logs. You should find a message like this:

```
o.s.w.s.e.mapping.UriEndpointMapping - Mapped key [/ws/CardInfoWS_v3] onto endpoint [bean 'cardInfoEndpointGateway_v3'; defined in: '...']
```

And the warn after sending request says:

```
o.s.w.s.e.mapping.UriEndpointMapping - Looking up endpoint for [/cms-ws/ws/CardInfoWS_v3]
o.s.ws.server.EndpointNotFound - No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {...}GetCardRequest]
```

So... it is looking for endpoint mapping under the key **"/cms-ws/ws/CardInfoWS_v3"** but the endpoint is registered under the key **"/ws/CardInfoWS_v3"**.

You can also put the breakpoint to the method **lookupEndpoint** in your endpoint mapper (**AbstractMapBasedEndpointMapping** or **AbstractMethodEndpointMapping**) that looks like this:

```
protected Object lookupEndpoint(String key) {
    return endpointMap.get(key);
}
```

and after sending the request, in the debug mode **you will see all your registered endpoints** and **the key which is currently searched**.

Answer (score 0):

context level parameters need to be reflected in MessageDispatcherServlet level also.

```html
<servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class> <br>
        <init-param> <br>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name> <br>
            <param-value>true</param-value> <br>
        </init-param> <br>
        <init-param> <br>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <br>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servesy-config.xml</param-value> <br>
        </init-param> <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

For what's it worth, I was facing this issue `2021-02-17 14:13:52.810 DEBUG 204429 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher  : Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@7f98f516] has no mapping for request`  while following - https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/- was that I somehow missed to annotate the the endpoint with `@Endpoint public class CountryEndpoint`